# Directory.GetFiles Not returning a file

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems

I have manually created a text file called AAAAA.txt in c:\windows\System32 , when I execute the following code:

```
var sys32Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\windows\System32");
```

It returns a bunch of files, but AAAAA.txt is not in that list. All permissions on the AAAAA.txt are the same as on those file that get returned.

Could someone explain what may be the issue here?

*And yes, I'm running as an administrator.*

Comment: are you on a x64 operating system?

Comment: yes I am, other directories seem to work just fine

Comment: thats why. windows will redirect to the other system32 directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a 64 bit machine and are running a 32 bit process. The [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx) means that `C:\Windows\system32` is redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. If you want to find files in `C:\Windows\system32` you can use the `C:\Windows\sysnative` alias. Or compile for 64 bit.

Of course you should not be creating files in the system directory in the first place. It belongs to Windows and you should leave it well alone.

Comment: Thanks David and Daniel, that answers my question.