# c# Directory.GetFiles() - multiple files on NTFS

Tags: c#, ntfs, getfiles, ntfs-mft

Using System.IO.Directory.GetFiles() like this

```
string[] fileFullPaths1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32", "mycompanyname.scr");
string[] fileFullPaths2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64", "mycompanyname.scr");
```

I find the following two files:

- C:\Windows\System32\mycompanyname.scr
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mycompanyname.scr

Windows explorer cannot see the one in C:\Windows\System32, nor can a command line dir. Furthermore, my own code that searches the MFT shows that there is only one instance of mycompanyname.scr in the MFT and its parent directory record number points to C:\Windows\SysWOW64, so I don't think that hard links are confusing the issue. I have also checked that neither of the two directories are junction points.

Could someone please explain why this is?

Comment: Probably http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your application is 32-bit, so its System32 directory is redirected to SysWOW64. Read [MSDN: File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It's almost certainly to do with the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) - @ta.speot.is - but I wouldn't link them directly to documentation about *disabling* it because that's usually the wrong thing to do.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't say much. But the intent was to get OP to read the documentation.

Comment: You have all been most helpful, and indeed fast! Thanks. WoW64 is not something I know much about, so time for some reading :)

Comment: Sure enough, if I build my little test program as 64-bit, I only see the one in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: I think that this answer might be useful for you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600921/directory-getfiles-not-returning-a-file

Answer (score 0):

`WOW64` means `Windows-on-Windows 64-bit`.

`SysWOW64` is used to put 32-bit program.
`System32` is used to put 64-bit program.

For 32-bit programs, `C:\Windows\System32` will always be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.
For 64-bit programs, `C:\Windows\System32` will be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` if file doesn't exist

You can complie your program to x86 and try again.